# How to use SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN correctly?

Tags: c++, c, sdl

I'm trying to use x and y coordinates from mouse for a game, but i can not get the coordinates.

This is the event i've been reading:

```
typedef struct{
    Uint8 type;
    Uint8 button;
    Uint8 state;
    Uint16 x, y;
} SDL_MouseButtonEvent;
```

I need something like:

```
if(SDL_MouseButtonEvent.x >= 100)
{
//do something
}
```

I think the sintax is very different because i saw some examples using SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN.

**EDIT**

I apologize, know this question might not be clear, but Peter's answer was just what I needed, thanks for your time.

Comment: Post the relevant piece of your code - it's not really clear what your problem is. The constant (all in capitals) is a flag that indicates the mouse button is down. So at that point you'd check the x and y positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to intercept a click in an specific area first you need to be polling the events and check for a SDL_MouseButtonEvent.

```
while(running)
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) // check to see if an event has happened
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                running = false;
                break;
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: // if the event is mouse click
                if(event.mouse.x >= 100)  // check if it is in the desired area
                {
                    //do something    
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank for your time, it's been pased along time but I'm greatful for your help.

Answer (score 4):

A quick precision: `event.mouse.x` has been replaced by `event.motion.x` and `event.motion.xrel` for respectively absolute and relative mouse movement, both `int`.